# AdSense live revenue per viewer

Tags: javascript, tracking, adsense, adsense-api

I'm trying to track how much revenue a viewer does when he comes on my page as fast as possible.

Someone clicks on a link that directs him to my webpage article "xyz" and now this viewer generates revenue through Adsense. As long as this guy does not go on any other article on my page his revenue counts for my article"xyz" even if he is on my list view for all my articles or on my profil.

When the viewer now visits my article "abc" the revenue counts for that  article.

This should work with ad clicks and ad views and as fast as possible.

Anyone solutions ?

Thank you very much for each answer and for the support!

Comment: Is what adsense reports tool do right?

Comment: No as far as I know it is the general real time revenue not specific for a viewer

Comment: All analytics in adsense dahsboard ...